# Where to find the ca.key on kubernetes helm installation on EKS

Tags: kubernetes, cockroachdb

probably super simple but my lack of experience with both kubernetes and cockroachdb makes it a bit difficult.

I have set up a EKS cluster of 2 nodes where I am running 2 replicas of cockroach DB. I have followed the documentation to install cockroachDB with helm. Now I am trying to access the database from my local machine by making an external connection.

When I run the cockroach-secure-client pod, bash in to it and try to create a new user certificate, it is asking me for my ca.key file. I have no clue where to find this. In '/cockroach-certs' you can find the ca.crt file, but I need the ca.key file.

Where am I suppose to find this?

Comment: Unless the docs are outdated, [secure setups with Helm don't work on EKS](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/orchestrate-cockroachdb-with-kubernetes.html#step-2-start-cockroachdb) due to the certificate manager setup on EKS. Can you point to the docs you followed?

Comment: I am so stupid :') Have set it up as stateful set without kubernetes CA and its working like a charm now. So stupid xD Thank you @Marc

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the Kubernetes CA key. See here: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/orchestrate-cockroachdb-with-kubernetes.html#initialize-the-cluster

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.